# DB2 rownum equivalent

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have the below query in Oracle which I want to replicate in DB2 which uses the random function and the rownum.

Oracle Query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (
   SELECT * 
   FROM db2admin.QUESTION_BANK 
   WHERE type='PROCESS' 
   ORDER BY dbms_random.value
) WHERE rownum <=?
```

I got alternate for random function but nothing for rownum. Below is query in DB2,

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (
  SELECT * 
  FROM db2admin.QUESTION_BANK 
  WHERE type='PROCESS' ORDER BY RAND
) WHERE rownum <= ?
```

The value for rownum is passed via PreparedStatement.

Comment: `fetch first .. rows only` or `row_number()`

Comment: But with row_number() can the random be used together?. Can you give an example?

Comment: `row_Number() over (order by rand)`

Comment: I get this error

The use of routine or expression "RAND" is invalid because it is not deterministic or has an external action.. SQLCODE=-583, SQLSTATE=42845, DRIVER=4.18.60

Comment: What version of which DB2?

Comment: Database server        = DB2/NT 10.5.4

Answer (score 3):

DB2 has [ROWNUM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052875.html) when you work in the Oracle compatibility mode. To enable just this feature, use this:

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=01
db2stop
db2start
```

To get all the Oracle features, enable it like this:

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA
db2stop
db2start
```

The doc on the [DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html) has details on alternatives like 
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`.

Comment: "DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.18.60

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM db2admin.QUESTION_BANK 
WHERE type = 'PROCESS' 
ORDER BY RAND() 
fetch first ? rows only;
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly. But one question here wont this only pick first say 20 questions everytime and randomize them?

Comment: @SouravMehra: no, the `order by` happens _before_ the `fetch first` is applied

Comment: RAND() is not necessary if you wanna see how a row looks like. Use it only if you are extracting a data sample.

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (
       SELECT f1.*, rownumber() over(ORDER BY f1.randm ) as rownum
       from ( 
            select f0.*, rand() as randm FROM db2admin.QUESTION_BANK f0
             WHERE f0.type='PROCESS'
            ) f1
      ) f2 
WHERE f2.rownum <= ?
```

Comment: `rand` is a function, not a column

Comment: Perfect. This exactly does the task needed.

Answer (score 1):

use ROW_NUMBER() analitical function as equivalent of rownum

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (
   SELECT db2admin.* 
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rownum 
   FROM db2admin.QUESTION_BANK 
   WHERE type='PROCESS' 
   ORDER BY dbms_random.value
) WHERE rownum <=?
```

or better yet, you can use `LIMIT` clausule

```
SELECT db2admin.* 
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rownum 
FROM db2admin.QUESTION_BANK 
WHERE type='PROCESS' 
ORDER BY dbms_random.value
LIMIT :number_of_skiped_rows , :number_of_displayed_rows;
```

Comment: easier using fetch as commented before, no need to use analytical functions over null partitioning clause